# Align <li> with <input> with the text

Tags: html, css, input, html-lists

I would like to align the text and input in the LI to be horizontaly aligned with the menu on the left. Here how it looks.

[image]

I need the newsletter to be align with the menu on the left.

**CSS**

```
#footer .div1{
    float:left;
}
#footer ul{
    list-style:none;
}
#footer li{
    float:left;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:18px;
}
#footer li:first-child{
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="div1">
    <ul>
      <li><b>WE &hearts; TO NETWORK</b></li>
      <li>FACEBOOK</li>
      <li>BLOG</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
      <li>NEWSLETTER : <input type="text" name="email" id="emailNl" style="font-family:arial; width:200px; margin:0px; padding:0px;"/> <span id="submitNl" style="cursor:pointer">OK</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

**IMAGE UPDATED!**

With padding and margin 0px it's almost there but you can notice a slight difference. :S

**UPDATE 2**

By changing the float:left of my LI to display:inline-block, now the text is align but the input seems to be like padding-top 2px too much ... I think i'll tweak this to make it fit and see through each browsers.

Comment: Copied your code into a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/6pBhd/) and there is no alignment issue.  Possibly you have some other css that is causing the problem?

Comment: seems like this occurs online is IE?

Comment: The input element is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reset the padding and margin of the element and try vertical-align property - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

although, I tested, they align just perfectly as it is. below is the preview from firefox

[image: li elements align with input element and text in html]

You can try

```
#footer ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type=text]{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

see if it works.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of this? I tried vertical-align and didn't have any luck.

Comment: put a vertical align on the li, span and the input. lemme post a jsfiddle too for this.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle, just drag the vertical separator till the li's align in one line - http://jsfiddle.net/bcAJC/

Comment: in-case you still need help, put it online - I will have a look!

Comment: The hell with it, for 2px ... they won't notice it :D Thanks

Comment: this really doesn't change anything... your solution depends on the font size. If you use a smaller font, you still have the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DFazq/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by `float: left;`. Replace it with `display: inline-block;` and you'll be fine.

Try it yourself: [inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/6Jm9r/) vs [float:left](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9nge/)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it in a jsfiddle. It looks to me like the input tag is trying to put some padding/margin (oh how I always forget which is which) around itself. Try setting those to 0px.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will look good but this sure does the job.

```
#emailNl{
margin-top:-3px;
}
```

Comment: you can add or reduce the margin and also adjust the border color etc to make it look "adjusted"